# Where to put heavy init operations in MvvmCross

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

In an MvvmCross ViewModel, the Init method is used for any screen initialization.  However, the screen is not drawn until Init is fully completed.  I have some heavy operations (db searching).  So ideally I would like to draw the screen with a progress bar, and then run my initialization methods, and finally update the screen.  Where would I put these operations in the MvvmCross ViewModel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do heavy stuff in a `Service`. In that service i would either:

- Make a method which triggers a `Done` event which you can listen for in your `ViewModel` and from there populate Properties with data.

or

- Make an async method which you await on a background thread and when it returns you populate Properties.

While this service runs and fetches data, I would simply display something else on the screen, while the data loads. This could be some cached data or a progress bar or something else.

Comment: +1 - although sometimes you need to be careful with the done event as this can lead to leaks if you never unsubscribe - in these cases it can be better to use a message subscription taking advantage of weak referencing.

Comment: But what triggers the service to begin it's operation?  If I trigger it from init, don't I have the same problem (since it's not async)?

Comment: This worked like a charm, and I'm able to do it all within the core project service.. my service method just uses a different thread to call the heavy operation, then fires a message when complete.

Comment: ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state =>
                {
                    var results = _repository.Find(filter);
                    _messenger.Publish(new SearchCompleteMessage(this, results));
                });